Sqlalchemy orm not updating the db correctly during power failure scenarios
def update_slot_details(data):
    try:
        context = data['context']
        del data['context']

        existing_record = session.query(Slot_details).filter(
            and_(Slot_details.trace_id == data['trace_id'], Slot_details.slot_id == data['slot_id'])).first()

        if existing_record:
            # Update existing record
            for attr, value in existing_record.__dict__.items():
                # Filter out non-model attributes
                if not attr.startswith("_"):
                    # Modify the attribute value here 
                    setattr(existing_record, attr, data.get(attr, value))
                    
            # Update associated Context record, if exists
            existing_context = session.query(Context).filter_by(trace_id=data['trace_id']).first()
            if existing_context:
                setattr(existing_context, 'context', context)
                session.add(existing_context)
            
            session.add(existing_record)
        else:
            # Create new Slot_details object
            slot_details = Slot_details()
            for key, value in data.items():
                if hasattr(slot_details, key):
                    if key != 'context':
                        setattr(slot_details, key, value)

            # Create or update Context object associated with Slot_details
            existing_context = session.query(Context).filter_by(trace_id=data['trace_id']).first()
            if existing_context:
                existing_context.context = context
                session.add(existing_context)
            else:
                contexts = Context(trace_id=data['trace_id'], context=context)
                session.add(contexts)

            session.add(slot_details)

        session.flush()
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        # Rollback the transaction in case of an error
        session.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        # Commit the transaction and close the session
        
        session.close()
        logging.info(f'state {data}')
        logging.info(f'context {context}')
     

I am using this function to update the tables in my db. This thread is going to be called by multiple threads. so any given point there is chance of multiple sessions opened. During power failure cases i want the first transaction to commit to db but the last transaction is getting stored to db.
and i am creating a session like below
engine = create_engine(config.nila_db_path, echo=False, pool_size=10, max_overflow=10)
Base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session.autocommit = False
session = Session()


i want the first transaction to commit to db instead of last transaction during the power failure

More to the point of the question: I don't think anything can be done at the Python level in the event of a power failure, at least not in SQLAlchemy: data is either, committed or flushed, otherwise it only exists in Python.  What matters, I'm guessing, is the configuration of SQLite's write ahead log (WAL) and (again, I'm guessing), the configuration of the filesystem.
